# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln{k}}{k^2}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln{k}}{k^2}$ converges or diverges

I know that I must use the Limit Comparison test and my instinct tells me that this series will converge. I cannot, however, think of another series $b_k$, to compare my given series to in order to show that it converges.

Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Tip: Use `\sum` rather than `\Sigma` next time.

Comment: @Alizter Thanks! Will do :)

Comment: It sums to $\zeta'(2)$, which apparently equals $-\frac{\pi^2}{6}(\gamma+12\zeta'(-1)+\ln2+\ln\pi-1)$ somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{ln}\ k}{k^2} < \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\text{ln}\ x}{x^2} dx = 1 $$

Answer (score 3):

- Try looking at the maximum value of the function $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $(1,\infty)$
- $\displaystyle f'(x)= \frac{2-\ln(x)}{2x^{3/2}}$
- $f'(x) <0$ for all $x>e^{2}$. Hence $f(x) \leq f(e^{2})$ for all $x\geq 1$. Hence $\displaystyle \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{2}{e}$.
- Now $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln{(k)}}{k^{2}} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(k)}{\sqrt{k}} \times \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} \leq \frac{2}{e} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} <\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Since

$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\ln k}}
{{\sqrt k }} = 0
$ you have that

1. There exists $k_0$ such that for each $k>k_0$  it is $
   \frac{{\ln k}}
   {{\sqrt k }} < 1
   $
2. This means that for each $k>k_0$ it is 
   $
   \frac{{\ln k}}
   {{k^2 }} < k^{ - \frac{3}
   {2}} 
   $
3. Since the series with general term $
   k^{ - \frac{3}
   {2}} 
   $ is convergent your series is also convergent by comparison test.

Answer (score -1):

Equals the constant in http://oeis.org/A073002 , which gives further links.