# An elementary proof for a series involving logarithm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that

$$ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \leq 1$$

in an elementary way, but haven't found such a proof yet. Would you please share with us if you find any elementary proof of the inequality?

Also, is there any elementary method to find upper bounds for series involving logarithms?

Comment: Maybe check Aaron's answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980972/show-that-sum-k-1-infty-frac-lnkk2-converges-or-diverges.

Comment: @Sil Thank you Sil, there was an answer same as Aaron's, but he/she deleted it after I asked him whether usage of integrals is elemantary sadly, whish he/she hadn't do that :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that

$$\int \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx = -\frac{1+ \ln x}{x}+ C$$

Since $\ln x / x^2$ is decreasing for $x > 2$, we have

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^2} &= \frac{\ln 2}{4} + \frac{\ln 3}{9}+\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^2} \\&< \frac{\ln 2}{4} + \frac{\ln 3}{9}+\int_3^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx \\&\approx 0.29535  + 0.69954 \\&= 0.99489\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, but after the usage of integrals, the proof is still elemantary?

Comment: @BrightChancellor, you'll need to be more specific about what you mean by "elementary"

Comment: @BrightChancellor: The integral has a closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @RRL Thank you, I have thought that you had deleted your answer :)

Comment: @BrightChancellor: You're welcome.  I was just editing to clear up the part about the integral. Also you have to go out a few terms because the function is not monotone for $1 < x < 2$ and $\int_1^2$ is not greater than $\ln2/4$.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative way is to exploit creative telescoping. One may prove the inequality
$$ \forall n\geq 2,\qquad \frac{\log n}{n^2}\leq \frac{\log(n+1)+1}{n}-\frac{\log(n+2)+1}{n+1}\tag{1} $$
and deduce from it that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log n}{n^2} \leq \frac{\log 2}{4}+\frac{\log(4)+1}{3} < 1 \tag{2}$$
since $\log(2)<\frac{8}{11}$. This can be shown via
$$ 0\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3(1-x)^3}{1+x}\,dx = \frac{111}{20}-8\log(2) \tag{3}$$
and $\frac{111}{160}<\frac{8}{11}.$

Comment: Nice solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th term and the rest can be replaced by the smaller $x^{-2}$, if we add the area between the graphs for $x^{-2}$ and $\log (x)x^{-2}$ starting one step earlier at $x=3$.

$$\sum_{x=1}^3\log(x)x^{-2}+\sum_{x=4}^{\infty}x^{-2}+\int_3^{\infty}(\log (x)x^{-2}-x^{-2})dx=\frac{6 \pi ^2-49+16 \log (3)+\log (512)}{36}$$

which is less than $1$.

Comment: Cool solution, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a taylor expansion for ln(x), Then dividing this by x^2. It should always be 1/x^n for each term in that expansion.

Comment: But isn't the taylor expansion for ln(x) only valid when -1<x<1?

Comment: ah true, are there any other expansions with a larger range?

Comment: Well, I don't really know :)

Comment: All power series expansions on the real line are symmetric around their point of expansion and stop (at one end) at $0$.  So there are series with wider ranges, but no one can work all the way out to the end of the series.  (That *might* not be fatal, expansions around $2^k$ would let you group exponentially many terms of the sum into chunks with a single Taylor expansion, which *might* lead to the desired bound...)